# Apply decorator to Python class

Tags: python, python-decorators

In C# it is possible to apply attributes to classes and properties, like the following example;

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName="Book")]
public class Book
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName="Title")]
    public string Title;

}
```

If I understand it correctly, in Python decorators are similar to attributes in C#. If it is the case, is it possible to apply a decorator to a python class, like the following example illustrates?

```
@XmlRoot(ElementName="Book")
class Book:

    @XmlElement(ElementName="Title")
    def Title(self)
        return self._title
```

Comment: That would be more or less equal to `Book = XmlRoot(ElementName="Book")(Book)`.

Comment: Yes, it's possible - see [Primer on Python Decorators - Creating Singletons](https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators/#creating-singletons) for an example.